# c++ pushing dereferenced objects to vector

Tags: c++, boost, reference, filesystems

I'm making a function to take in a reference to a path on the filesystem and recursively add file names to a vector. But first I have to be able to add paths to a vector.

what is wrong with this method?

```
namespace filesys = boost::filesystem;
```

Method:

```
void recursive_file_list(filesys::path & root_path, vector<filesys::path> & paths) {
    paths->push_back(*root_path);    // line 14

    // TODO: add more logic to actually recurse through file system
    // for now just add root_path (even though root_path is path of directory, not file)
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        // Use the command line arguments
        filesys::path abs_path;    // line 23
        if ( argc > 1 )
            // Make the system complete this path to absolute path
            abs_path = filesys::system_complete( filesys::path( argv[1] ) );
        else {
            // If no arguments given
            cout << "usage:   list_files [path]" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        // Is this a valid path?
        if (!filesys::exists( abs_path )) {
            cout << "The path you have specified does not exist." << endl; 
            exit(2);
        }

        // If this is a directory
        vector<filesys::path> filepaths();   
        if (filesys::is_directory( abs_path )) {
            cout << "You have specified a directory." << endl;
            recursive_file_list(&abs_path, &filepaths);
        }

        else {
            cout << "You have specified a file." << endl;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
list_files.cpp: In function 'void recursive_file_list(boost::filesystem3::path&, std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> >&)':
list_files.cpp:14: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> >'
list_files.cpp:14: error: no match for 'operator*' in '*root_path'
list_files.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
list_files.cpp:43: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'boost::filesystem3::path&' from a temporary of type 'boost::filesystem3::path*'
list_files.cpp:13: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void recursive_file_list(boost::filesystem3::path&, std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> >&)'
```

I don't understand - I'm passing it by reference and then dereferencing it to add it...not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: why the -1? I'm not very good with C++ but I didn't think that meant I shouldn't ask it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dereference references! The `*` and `->` operators do not apply to references; you would push the `path` itself to the `vector` itself:

```
paths.push_back(root_path);    // line 14
```

and furthermore, you don't pass addresses to reference arguments, just the arguments themselves, so you would call the function like this:

```
recursive_file_list(abs_path, filepaths);
```

References have pointer-like non-copy semantics all by themselves; you do not need to help them along by taking addresses or trying to dereference them.

Comment: Indeed, and that's what will happen. Because the parameters of `recursive_file_list()` are reference parameters, that `push_back` in `recursive_file_list()` affects the `vector` declared in `main()`. That's the whole point of reference parameters!

Comment: My thinking was that because the `path` I passed in was a reference, then adding that variable the vector would be adding a reference. Does C++ automatically dereference it before adding it?

Comment: Any object you add to a `vector` will be a copy of what you pass in. If the `vector` must refer to some specific `path` objects, then it has to be a `vector` of pointers (`vector`s of references are not legal C++); you must declare it as such. The way you've declared your `vector`, it can only contain copies of the objects you pass in.

Comment: oh I see. the push_back function is overloaded? so it must implicitly dereference the reference, clone the original object, and THEN add it to the vector. if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: ok. well making the changes @ErnestFriedman-Hill suggested lead to: `list_files.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
list_files.cpp:43: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> >&' from a temporary of type 'std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> > (*)()'
list_files.cpp:13: error: in passing argument 2 of 'void recursive_file_list(boost::filesystem3::path&, std::vector<boost::filesystem3::path, std::allocator<boost::filesystem3::path> >&)'`

Comment: It's not that the method is overloaded; it's just the semantics of the language and how the compiler generates code. As I said, you can't "dereference a reference," nor do you need to; rather, the compiler simply takes care of passing reference arguments without making copies by generating the appropriate code.

Comment: The error message implies that you're still passing the pointer-to-vector as the second argument to the function at line 43.

Comment: no, the method signature still reads `vector<filesys::path> & paths` as the parameter, which isn't a pointer. see here for all code: http://pastebin.com/tzfAxuCN

Comment: I didn't notice this before: the declaration "vector<filesys::path> filepaths();" is not a variable -- it's a forward declaration of a function named filepaths that returns a vector! The correct declaration would look like "vector<filesys::path> filepaths;", no parentheses. This is generally true -- those empty parentheses must be left off. This is what the error message is referring to.

Comment: ah yes. good point. thanks for all your help! really appreciate it! c++ takes a while to learn.